# Must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, external, dllimport

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "GetAsyncKeyState", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        public static int KeyPress2(int key);
```

(These are the only bits that affect it.

Comment: I think it should have extern in it, e.g.: `public static extern int KeyPress2(int key);`

Comment: Isn't the error message telling you what's wrong? This method cannot logically be `abstract` or `partial`, so you are missing an `extern`.

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the "external" modifier:
the method is a part of a external dll (unmanaged, i think)